# DAX | To override active filter with Inactive (Userelationship)

Tags: dax, tabular

I need a help in creating DAX measures. Here is the relationship in Tabular cube.
I have one Fact sales, Initial Date, final Date and product table.

```
Relationship : Product -> Fact Sales (1 to Many, active)
Initial Date -> Fact Sales (1 to many, inactive relation)
Final Date - > Fact Sales(1 to many, active)
```

Cube is used as source for Power Bi tools. Users can select any initial and final date for comparison of sales.

Actual data

```
Product|Date|Sales
Product1|20160101|100
Product1|20160102|110
Product1|20160131|200
Product2|20160101|78
.....
```

Expected output 
**Filters :**

```
product : Product1
Initial date : 20160101
Final Date : 20160131

Product | Initial Sales | Final Sales
Product1|100 |200
```

I have created DAX measure AS

```
Initial Sales := CALCULATE(SUM(SALES),USERELATIONSHIP('Fact Sales'[Date],'Initial Date'[Date]))
```

But this measure is not giving me initial sales as it is also filtered by final date.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can relate tables without an explicit relationship by using FILTER function in DAX.

Since `Initial Date` relationship with `Fact Sales` is disabled, you need to `FILTER` the `Fact Sales` rows that match the `Initial Date` selected in the filter. You can use `EARLIER` to compare the context being evaluated against each row in `Fact Sales` and filter the right values for the calculation.

Use these measures:

```
Initial Sales :=
IF (
    ISFILTERED ( InitialDate[InitialDate] ),
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( FactSales[Sales] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( FactSales ),
            COUNTROWS (
                FILTER (
                    FactSales,
                    EARLIER ( FactSales[Date] ) = MAX ( InitialDate[InitialDate] )
                        && EARLIER ( FactSales[Product] ) = [Product]
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    BLANK ()
)
```

```
Final Sales :=
IF (
    ISFILTERED ( FinalDate[FinalDate] ),
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( FactSales[Sales] ),
        FILTER ( FactSales, [Date] = MAX ( FinalDate[FinalDate] ) )
    ),
    BLANK ()
)
```

This expression works as follows, it sums all values in `Sales` column which `Date` is equal to the `Final Date` selected in the filter. However this can be calculated easily as you know with the relationship you have set between `Final Date` and `Fact Sales`.

The `ISFILTERED` functions tell us if the filter have a value selected or not, if a value is selected it returns the value otherwise returns `BLANK`.

This is an example in Power BI since I don't have access to Excel right now.

[image]